# $request->all() is always empty

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, laravel-passport

I am using **Laravel 5** with passport package to manage users action, everything was working as expected until one day no API is working when I try to send a request to register API nothing happens and try to test with postman and i found request is `array(0){}`!!!, the request is null here is the API route

```php
Route::group(['namespace' => 'User', 'prefix' => '/User'], function(){
    Route::post('Login','UserAuthController@Login');
    Route::post('ForgetPassword','UserAuthController@ForgetPassword');
    Route::post('Register','UserAuthController@Register');
}
```

here is the code I am using to register

```php
public function Register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make(
        $request->all(),
        [
            'title_id' => 'required',
            'first_name' => 'required|min:3',
            'last_name' => 'required|min:3',
            'name' => 'required|min:3',
            'UserName' => 'required|min:3',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
            'passwordConfirm' => 'required|same:password',
            'dateofbirth' => 'required',
            'Address' => 'required',
            'region_id' => 'required',
            'city_id' => 'required',
            'country_id' => 'required',
            'work_mobile' => 'required'

        ],
        [
            'required'=>'You cant leave :attribute field empty',
            'passwordConfirm.same'=> ':attribute should match the password field ',
            'min'=>'The :attribute has to be :min chars long',
        ]
    );

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'Success' => false,
            'Message' => $validator->messages(),
            'Data' => null,
        ], $this->FailedStatus);
    }

    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
    if ($user === null) {
        $input = $request->all();
        $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);
        $input['passwordConfirm'] = bcrypt($input['passwordConfirm']);
        $input['is_active'] = 0;

        $billing = [
            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
            'last_name' => $request->last_name,
            'company' => '',
            'address_1' => $request->Address,
            'address_2' => '',
            'city' => 'EF',
            'state' => 'EF',
            'postcode' => '',
            'country' => 'EG',
            'email' => $request->email,
            'phone' => $request->work_mobile
        ];

        $shipping = [
            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
            'last_name' => $request->last_name,
            'company' => '',
            'address_1' => $request->Address,
            'address_2' => '',
            'city' => 'EF',
            'state' => 'EF',
            'postcode' => '',
            'country' => 'EG',
        ];

        $data = [
            'email' => $request->email,
            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
            'last_name' => $request->last_name,
            'username' => $request->UserName,
            'password' => $request->password,
            'billing' => $billing,
            'shipping' => $shipping
        ];

        $Customer = app(wooClient::class)->wp_register_newcustomer($data);
        if ( $Customer === null)
        {
            return response()->json([
                'Success' => true,
                'Message' => $Customer,
                'Data' => $Customer,
                'BaseURL' => null,
            ], 401);
        }

        $input['wpuserid'] = $Customer->id;

        $InsertUser = User::create($input);
        $success['token'] = $InsertUser->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
        $success['userDetails'] = $InsertUser->load('Background')->load('ProfilePic');
        $success['videos'] = $this->getLastVideoForUser();


        return response()->json([
            'Success' => true,
            'Message' => $validator->messages(),
            'Data' => $success,
            'BaseURL' => null,
        ], 200);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'Success' => false,
        'Message' => $validator->messages(),
        'Data' => null,
    ], $this->FailedStatus);
}
```

Postman returns:

```sh
Request {#43
    #json: null
    #convertedFiles: null
    #userResolver: Closure($guard = null) {#803
    class: "Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider"
    this: AuthServiceProvider {#23 …}
    parameters: {
      $guard: {
        default: null
      }
    }
    use: {
      $app: Application {#2 …}
    }
    file: "/home/ahameed/SmartWave/Mobile/NagwaZahran/nz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthServiceProvider.php"
    line: "83 to 85"
    }
    #routeResolver: Closure() {#805
    class: "Illuminate\Routing\Router"
    this: Router {#26 …}
    use: {
      $route: Route {#420 …}
    }
    file: "/home/ahameed/SmartWave/Mobile/NagwaZahran/nz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php"
    line: "650 to 652"
    }
    +attributes: ParameterBag {#45
    #parameters: []
    }
    +request: ParameterBag {#44
    #parameters: []
    }
    +query: ParameterBag {#51
    #parameters: []
    }
    +server: ServerBag {#47
    #parameters: array:26 [
      "DOCUMENT_ROOT" => "/home/ahameed/SmartWave/Mobile/NagwaZahran/nz/public"
      "REMOTE_ADDR" => "127.0.0.1"
      "REMOTE_PORT" => "32852"
      "SERVER_SOFTWARE" => "PHP 7.2.18 Development Server"
      "SERVER_PROTOCOL" => "HTTP/1.1"
      "SERVER_NAME" => "127.0.0.1"
      "SERVER_PORT" => "8001"
      "REQUEST_URI" => "/api/User/Register"
      "REQUEST_METHOD" => "POST"
      "SCRIPT_NAME" => "/index.php"
      "SCRIPT_FILENAME" => "/home/ahameed/SmartWave/Mobile/NagwaZahran/nz/public/index.php"
      "PATH_INFO" => "/api/User/Register"
      "PHP_SELF" => "/index.php/api/User/Register"
      "HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL" => "no-cache"
      "HTTP_POSTMAN_TOKEN" => "99fc7dac-8fb7-4e26-b3d7-d86170405970"
      "CONTENT_TYPE" => "text/plain"
      "HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE" => "text/plain"
      "HTTP_USER_AGENT" => "PostmanRuntime/7.6.1"
      "HTTP_ACCEPT" => "*/*"
      "HTTP_HOST" => "127.0.0.1:8001"
      "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" => "gzip, deflate"
      "CONTENT_LENGTH" => "23"
      "HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH" => "23"
      "HTTP_CONNECTION" => "keep-alive"
      "REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT" => 1559040214.0144
      "REQUEST_TIME" => 1559040214
    ]
    }
    +files: FileBag {#48
    #parameters: []
    }
    +cookies: ParameterBag {#46
    #parameters: []
    }
    +headers: HeaderBag {#49
    #headers: array:9 [
      "cache-control" => array:1 [
        0 => "no-cache"
      ]
      "postman-token" => array:1 [
        0 => "99fc7dac-8fb7-4e26-b3d7-d86170405970"
      ]
      "content-type" => array:1 [
        0 => "text/plain"
      ]
      "user-agent" => array:1 [
        0 => "PostmanRuntime/7.6.1"
      ]
      "accept" => array:1 [
        0 => "*/*"
      ]
      "host" => array:1 [
        0 => "127.0.0.1:8001"
      ]
      "accept-encoding" => array:1 [
        0 => "gzip, deflate"
      ]
      "content-length" => array:1 [
        0 => "23"
      ]
      "connection" => array:1 [
        0 => "keep-alive"
      ]
    ]
    #cacheControl: array:1 [
      "no-cache" => true
    ]
    }
    #content: null
    #languages: null
    #charsets: null
    #encodings: null
    #acceptableContentTypes: null
    #pathInfo: "/api/User/Register"
    #requestUri: "/api/User/Register"
    #baseUrl: ""
    #basePath: null
    #method: "POST"
    #format: null
    #session: null
    #locale: null
    #defaultLocale: "en"
    -isHostValid: true
    -isForwardedValid: true
    basePath: ""
    format: "html"
}
```

Comment: You should post a screenshot of your request on postman.

Comment: What changed that day?